# Is 'the vast extent of literature' singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number

I have the following question:

The vast extent of literature **provide** or **provides** a useful platform to measure fund performance.

Comment: Welcome! - As this is a site about English, could you use proper punctuation and capital letters please? Thanks.  'extent' is singular and 'literature' is singular, so the verb must be singular and is therefore 'provides'.

Comment: Hint: when you see "*the* X", X is singular.

Comment: @DanBron *The 39 Steps*? *The knights of the round table*? *Goldilocks and the Three Bears*?

Comment: @StoneyB Fair enough, fair enough.

Comment: The extent is singular; the extensions are plural.

Answer (score 2):

Extent is singular and carries the meaning of area. Vast would modify that in size, but not in plurality. I think we are somewhat slowed down in analyzing this by thinking of examples of literature, but as characterized by a vast extent, it remains singular and "provides" would be the right choice.